# Why is pthread_equal threadsafe?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

If I look at the implementation of `pthread_equal` it looks as follows:

```
int
__pthread_equal (pthread_t thread1, pthread_t thread2)
{
  return thread1 == thread2;
}
weak_alias (__pthread_equal, pthread_equal)
```

with

```
typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
```

Posix documentation says `pthread_equal` is threadsafe. But the call to `pthread_equals` copies and therefore accesses the `thread1` and `thread2` variables. If those variables are global and changed in this moment by another thread this would lead to undefined behavior.

So should `pthread_t` not be an atomic? Or does it behave atomically which is ensured in some other way?

Comment: You say "the implementation" as if there were only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation of `pthread_equal` (which is going to be specific to the POSIX implementation it goes with) does not access any variables except local ones. In C, arguments are always **passed by value**. `thread1` and `thread2` are local variables in the function who take their values from the expressions the caller uses when making the call.

With that said, even if they weren't, there would be no problem of thread-unsafety here. Rather, if the caller accessed `pthread_t` objects that could be changed concurrently by other threads without using appropriate synchronization mechanisms to preclude that, it's a data race bug in the caller, not a thread-safety matter in the callee.

Answer (score 0):

When we say an operation is thread safe, we make certain assumptions on the code that invokes that operation. Those assumptions include making sure the inputs to the operation are stable and that their values remain valid and stable until the operation completes. Otherwise, nothing would be thread safe.